# Azure node.js relative paths with graphql cli

Tags: node.js, azure, prisma

I have a small node.js application acting as a graph-api created with graphql-cli.
Everything works fine on localhost, but when I try to run it in azure as a web app, I seem to have a problem with paths. The below snippet is working on localhost running npm start

```
const server = new GraphQLServer({
  typeDefs: './src/schema.graphql',
  resolvers,
  context: req => ({
    ...req,
    db: new Prisma({
      typeDefs: 'src/generated/prisma.graphql',
      endpoint: 'xxx',
      secret: 'xxx',
      debug: true,
    }),
  }),
})
```

The path to one of the .graphql-file is defined:

```
typeDefs: './src/schema.graphql',
```

Which I find a bit weird considering the folder structure where index.js is in the same folder as schema.graphql

[image]

Anyhow, this is working on localhost, but when trying to run it as an azure web app I get the following error:

```
No schema found for path: D:\home\site\wwwroot\src\src\schema.graphql
```

Since this is just a scaffolded app, I don't want to change the paths in code. I don't think they are wrong since it is working on localhost. I´m thinking that I'm missing some configuration on azure.

This is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>      
      <add name="iisnode" path="src/index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>        
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^src/index.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>        
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="src/index.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>    
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And my iisnode.yml looks just like this:

```
nodeProcessCommandLine: "D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\8.4.0\node.exe"
```

I´ve tried a bunch of different node versions, but I'm currently running 8.4.0 on my localhost where its working

Anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `index.js` file to your root and change the `web.config` to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>      
      <add name="iisnode" path="index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>        
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^index.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>        
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>    
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Yeah sure, that will make it work on azure but it still doesn´t explain why it is working on localhost. I really feel there is something i´m missing on my azure setup.